# good favicon creation software

Tags: favicon

i know how to create a favion but with the help of a website....is there any free software to make cool favicons

Comment: Any icon creation software will do the job. I like [IcoFX](http://icofx.ro/).

Comment: Are you looking for free or paid solutions? I have used [Axialis Icon Workshop](http://www.axialis.com/iconworkshop/) in the past and it faired rather well. Unfortunately it's not free...

Comment: @Khez: The question explicitly asks about "free software to make cool favicons".

Comment: @Cody, my bad, downloaded IcoFX, nice simple app, has mild issues with borders and transparency, but really nice. Ty for the link.

Comment: @Khez: I've never once had an issue with transparency in IcoFX. What do you mean by that? (And I've never used borders on an icon. I'm not sure what that means, either.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out http://www.favicon.cc/

Sorry, I didn't read your question properly.
You can try http://www.adsensoftware.com/favicon/setup.exe

Comment: He says he knows how to create favicons with the help of a website already.